# Tell-tale signs of ability to present information in clear and elegant visual form

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality

How does one's ability to present (systemize) information into a clear and understandable format (e.g. through tables/ diagrams/ interactive interfaces/ multimedia/ etc) usually show?

(In other words, how can you spot "a born information architect"?)

I guess some psychometric tests measure that, but is there anything more immediate? E.g. my own suspicion is that a trait of such gift would have something to do with pursuit of efficiency in life and aversion to unnecessary complication in all its forms - visual ones, as well as social ones (e.g. bureaucracy, wordiness, hypocrisy, etc).

Comment: What are the ways that researchers operationalize the idea of "ability to systemize information in an elegant visual way?" I think it's important to nail down this concept in order to make this question answerable.

Comment: @Josh - what I have in mind is preparing easy to understand tables/ diagrams/ web interfaces/ etc